# JQuery - Display the selected option in dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have 5 dropdowns, when users select the option for each drop down,I want to display the selected item in front of each drop downs.

I know how to show for one drop down but when I have more than one dropdown I cant do it.

Comment: Can show us your current jquery code?

Comment: Please include code in your question.. this seems quite vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<select id='addl'>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id='add2'>
 <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
<select id='add3'>
<option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>

<p id="a1"> </p>
<p id="a2"> </p>
<p id="a3"> </p>
```

CSS:

```
p{
  display: inline;
}
```

JS:

```
 $('#addl').on('change',function(){
$("#a1").append().html("<p>" + $("#add1 option:selected").val() + "</p>");
})

$('#add2').on('change',function(){
$("#a2").append().html("<p>" + $("#add2 option:selected").val() + "</p>");

})

$('#add3').on('change',function(){
$("#a3").append().html("<p>" + $("#add3 option:selected").val() + "</p>");

})
```

Comment: can I put these jquerys in array ???because the number of the drop downs are dynamic.